# How do I create a login system that is to Sign in with Instagram in my app in Smartface?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, smartface.io

How do I create a login system that is to Sign in with Instagram in my app in Smartface?

Thank you

I've tried using the Instagram app but it didn't go well.

[image]

Comment: No i meant how to add this onto your app so that users can sign in to Instagram to view the rest of the app.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1EDZUDdVwHTRI1723Hv4yunZ7BChrdyJ1ni-vMUAq5rE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want to authenticate user and get the access token and user id of the the user from Instagram then you can use instagram's [Authentication API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/). But before publishing your app you will have to put it for review from Instagram. There are some privacy policies and quota limits, so check that too before using it.